# Filter data in angular JS Controller file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

in the below function the element data contains multiple record sets. 
What I want to do is filter it so that it returns only the row which has id same as 'selectedModelDrv'. I tried but getting all sorts of errors, can someone tell me the angular way of doing it?

```
vm.driverModelSelectorGo = function () {

        var selectedModelDrv = vm.driver.driverModelId;
        return datacontext.lookup.getLookupList(datacontext.lookupLists.driverModel).then(function (data) {
            //Filter 'data' so that data.driverModelId == selectedModelDrv
        })
    };
```

**Regards Max**

Comment: Lodash `.filter`? https://lodash.com/docs#filter - or just loop through the data add an `if` conditional and push the item to a new array if it fits your conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject $filter to your controller

```
function myCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
}
```

Then wherever you want to use that filter, just use it like this:

```
 $filter('filter');
```

Like this :

```
vm.driverModelSelectorGo = function () {    
        var selectedModelDrv = vm.driver.driverModelId;
        return datacontext.lookup.getLookupList(datacontext.lookupLists.driverModel).then(function (data) {
            $scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')(data,{id:selectedModelDrv});
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is an array, then you can use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter the data array and return only results matching your condition.

```
vm.driverModelSelectorGo = function () {
     var selectedModelDrv = vm.driver.driverModelId;
     return datacontext.lookup.getLookupList(datacontext.lookupLists.driverModel).then(function (data) {
        return data.filter(function(value) {
           return value.driverModelId == selectedModelDrv;
         });
     })
 };
```